# Eclipse attribute required is not defined annotation XmlElementRef

Tags: java, eclipse, jaxb

I work with java 1.6. I don't work with maven. In the lib folder I have the jar

```
jaxb-api-2.2.jar
```

When I build the project I get the error

```
attribute required is not defined annotation XmlElementRef
```

I have other jars

```
jaxb-api
jaxb-core.jar
jaxb-impl.jar
jaxb-impl-2.2.7-sources.jar
jaxb-jxc.jar
jaxb-xjc.jar
jaxb-xjc-2.2.7.jar
```

What jaxb version do I have to use with java 1.6?

Comment: The [`required` attribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementRef.html#required--) on the `XmlElementRef` annotation is new since JAXB 2.2. You say you have `jaxb-api-2.2.jar`, but it looks like you do not have this in your classpath, or that some other (older) version of JAXB is being picked up instead.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the error adding jaxb-api-2.2.jar